# IE11 calls onInput handler after creating input with value with diacritics (elements created by jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I create input by jquery and register onInput handler on that.

```
$('body').append($('<input id="input1" class="test-input" type="text" value="X ř "/>'));
$('.test-input').on('input', function(){
    console.log('called onInput: ', $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

See     http://jsfiddle.net/1cmo1yko/13/     . If the value of input is **with diacritics**, IE11 calls onInput handler. If there isn't diacritics or if it's in antoher browser (IE9, Chrome, Firefox), the handler isn't called.

Is it a bug? (I think it is). If it's the bug, is in jquery or in IE11?

Thanks.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this bug. Your question helped me figure out that diacritics were the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer your question: it seems to be a bug in IE, since you can reproduce the same behaviour in vanilla JS:

```
<input id="input1" class="test-input" type="text" value="X ř "/>

document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener('input', function() {
    console.log("Triggered!");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1cmo1yko/16/