# The IE (v: 11.162.x) triggers the wrong event in the IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, diacritics

I opened a bug in the bug tracker, but it was directly closed.
So I hope that I get more help here.

If I run my demo in the IE 11.162.10586.0 I get the alert dialog with "Problem". In all other browsers it work as expected. The problem is only there if I have German umlauts in the textbox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Bug Demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Demo project</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="content">
      <input type="text" id="#tbDemo" name="tbDemo" value="Demo (äöü)" />
      <h2>This does not work in the Internet Explorer</h2>
      <p><strong>Version: 11.162.10586.0</strong>
      </p>

      <h3>Problem</h3>
      <p>Only in the Internet Explorer (with that version - not Edge!) you can see the javascript alert with "Problem!"</p>
      <p>Without (äöü) in the textbox it works as expected.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#content").find("input").on('input', function() {
        alert('Problem!');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I made a screencast to show the problem:
http://screencast.com/t/RrHMleAVN3sj

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Apparently IE11 `input` events are quite buggy to say the least, and apparently Microsoft refuses to fix it](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810538/ie-11-fires-input-event-on-focus). That said, your question seems to be a duplicate of [IE11 calls onInput handler after creating input with value with diacritics (elements created by jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376520/ie11-calls-oninput-handler-after-creating-input-with-value-with-diacritics-elem). It's a super hacky fix, but could you replace the attribute with javascript afterwards and avoid diacritics?